# php Create account page with not redirect to index.html

Tags: php, database, html, redirect, header

THis website is for a shipping company where users create an accocunt and get a 
 somewhat virtual mailbox in another country. When the user creates an account his information is supposed to be sent to the database, and he should be redirected to dashboard.html, However when the create account form is filled out and the submit button pressed the user is supposed to be redirected to index.html but the page wont redirect. and there are no errors even with php error reporting on please help .

```
   <?php
   session_start();

   ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
   error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);


       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

         //check if variables are empty

     if (!empty($firstname) || !empty($lastname) || !empty($email) || 
         !empty($confirmemail) ||
         !empty($password) || !empty($confirmpassword)  || 
         !empty($phonenumber)    || !empty($address)  || !empty($city)  || 
         !empty($parish)  || !empty($trn)  ) 

        {
          $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
           $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
           $email= $_POST['email'];
           $confirmemail = $_POST['confirmemail'];
           $password = $_POST['password'];
           $confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];
           $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
           $address= $_POST['address'];
           $city = $_POST['city'];
           $parish = $_POST['parish'];
           $trn = $_POST['trn'];


       $DB_NAME= "ship2yaad";
       $DB_USER="root";
        $DB_PASSWORD="";
        $DB_HOST= "localhost";

    //create connection

     $conn= new mysqli("$DB_HOST", "$DB_USER", "$DB_PASSWORD","$DB_NAME");


   if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
   die('Connect Error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'.mysqli_connect_error());
    } 



     $SELECT = "SELECT email From usersdb Where email = ? Limit 1";
     $INSERT = "INSERT Into usersdb (firstname , lastname , email 
       ,confirmemail , password , confirmpassword , phonenumber, address, 
         city, parish ,trn) 
  values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
 //Prepare statement
   # code...



    $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($email);
    $stmt->store_result();
   $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;


    if ($rnum==0) {
        $stmt->close();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);

  // prepare and bind
     $stmt->bind_param("ssssssisssi", $firstname, $lastname, $email, 
      $confirmemail, $password, $confirmpassword ,$phonenumber, 
      $address, $city, $parish , $trn); 
     //binds the parameters to the SQL query and tells the database what the 
    parameters are
      $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();



        header('Location:dashboard.html');
        }



    ?>
     the database credentials are correct im 100% sure of it. PLus im not getting a sql connect error.
```

Comment: Try adding a space e.g. `header('Location: dashboard.html');`

Comment: i posted this code by accident IM VERY SORRY the real code was posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your codes;

**1. Repeat Definitions**

```
   ini_set('display_errors', 'On');   // useless because its overwritten
   error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);  //  uselesss again

   ini_set('display_errors', 1);   // repeat
   error_reporting(E_ALL);   // repeat
```

Don't repeat. Pick one and stick with it.

**2. Improper closing of loops**
Lots of closing braces are not present, results in harder debugging.

**3. The ROOT Cause of your problem.**
Incorrect usage of code comments.

```
//Prepare statement
# code...
```

Single line comments start with `//` and, as the name suggests, should end in the same line.
`# code` in the code (snippet above) slips in a different line.
If you'd rather use multi-line comments, the correct syntax is

```
/* Multi
   Line
   Comment */
```

this also occurs here ↓

```
//binds the parameters to the SQL query and tells the database what the 
    parameters are
```

Notice the difference in code's color ↑

***My advice*** — 
Use an IDE that offers PHP support and syntax highlighting.
Atom, Visual Studio Code, PhpStorm etc.